# Empty Page(Razor v3) is not showing in Add new Items in visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#

In visual studio 2013 when i create  Asp.Net Empty website after that when i add new items it does not show Empty Page(Razor v3) or any thing related to Razor like helper (Razor v3 ) or (content Razor v3)

Comment: check out [This walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  Step 1 is installing the razor tools.  It looks to me like you might not have them installed

Comment: while creating Asp.Net Empty Website  the Asp.Net  Website(Razor v2) and   Asp.Net  Website(Razor v3 ) options are available so i think i installed razor tools other wise these option wont display